# Returning SQL in text to model in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework

I have the parents class and the state class:

```
[Table("tb_pais")]
public class PaisModel
{
        [Key]
        [Column("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("nome")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo nome é obrigatório")]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [Column("sigla")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo sigla é obrigatório")]
        public string Sigla { get; set; }
}

[Table("tb_estado")]
public class EstadoModel
{
        [Key]
        [Column("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("nome")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo nome é obrigatório")]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [Column("sigla")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo sigla é obrigatório")]
        public string Sigla { get; set; }

        [Column("id_pais")]
        [ForeignKey("Pais")]
        public int IdPais { get; set; }

        public virtual PaisModel Pais { get; set; }
}
```

How to use the following SQL code and return to my class with the `EstadoModel` information and inside it as well the `PaisModel` information that are related to `EstadoModel`?

```
var sql = "SELECT A.id, A.nome, A.sigla, A.id_pais as IdPais FROM dbo.tb_estado A " +
          "INNER JOIN dbo.tb_pais B ON (A.id_pais = B.id) " +
          filtroWhere + paginacao;

ret = db.Database.SqlQuery<EstadoModel>(sql).ToList();
```

my filtroWhere and paginacao are the following:

```
        if (pagina > 0 && tamPag > 0)
        {
            if (pagina == 1)
            {
                pagina = pagina - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                pagina = ((pagina * tamPag) - tamPag) - 1;
            }

            paginacao = string.Format(" A.nome LIMIT {0} OFFSET {1}", tamPag, pagina);
        }

        var filtroWhere = "";
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filtro))
        {
            filtroWhere = string.Format(" where lower(A.nome) like '%{0}%'", filtro.ToLower());
        }


        if (idPais > 0)
        {
            filtroWhere += (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filtroWhere) ? " and" : "where") + string.Format(" B.id = {0}", idPais);
        }
```

Comment: Your `filtro` is open to SQL injection. I would strongly encourage not doing that.

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using LINQ?

Comment: @PeterSmith I do not know how to use LINQ in cases where where can change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using EntityFramework, I assume in your DBContext class you have `DBSet<EstadoModel> EstadoModels`

Then you can use

```
var items = db.EstadoModels.Include("Pais");
```

and add your filters

```
items.Where(x=> x.Paris.Id == idParis);
```

and your limits

```
items.Take(10).Skip(10);
```

and to return the list

```
items.ToList();
```

Comment: Technically, you don't need the include statement as nothing from `Pais` is being returned in his original select. It's only a filter.

Comment: You are correct, I included it to have EF generate the most similar SQL to the example that was provided.